# localizing coordinate in kivy

Tags: kivy

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        (x, y) = **self.parent.to_parent**(touch.x, touch.y)

        if self.selected and self.parent.collide_point(x-self.width/2,y-self.height/2):

            self.translate(touch.x - self.ix, touch.y - self.iy)
            return True
        return super().on_touch_move(touch)

def translate(self,x,y):
        self.center_x = self.ix = self.ix + x
        self.center_y = self.iy = self.iy + y
```

Please explain me what `to_parent()` and `collide_point()` functions mean.

Comment: Did you read docs? 

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.collide_point 

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#coordinate-transformations Is there any specific about these functions unclear?

Answer (score 0):

> **Please explain me what** `to_parent()` and `collide_point()` **functions mean**

### From the docs:

- `to_parent()`:

  `to_parent()` takes the coordinates expressed in local coordinates and returns them in parent coordinates. Notice that the parent is the widget that directly contents this widget.
- `collide_point()`:

  Check if a point `(x, y)` is inside the widget’s axis aligned bounding box. It's generally used in the different `on_touch_` events to check if the `pos` of the touch collide with the widget

Comment: Thank you . I have gone through documentation